# JSON - reading nested data from a json file?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

Here is my JSON data :

```
{
    "main": [
        {
            "main_id": "1234",
            "main_sub": [
                {
                    "main_info": {
                        "main_1" : "A",
                        "main_2" : "B",
                        "main_3" : "C"
                    },
                    "main_4" : "D",
                    "main_5" : "E",
                },
                {
                    "main_6" : "F",
                    "main_7" : "G",
                    "main_info": {
                        "main_1" : "H",
                        "main_2" : "I",
                        "main_3" : "J"
                    },
                    "main_4" : "D",
                    "main_5" : "E",  
                    "main_act": [
                        {
                            "main_act_1": 12,
                            "main_act_1_1": "C",
                            "main_act_1_2": "T"
                        },
                        {
                            "main_act_1": 12,
                            "main_act_1_1": "D",
                            "main_act_1_2": "T"
                        }
                    ],
                    "main_8" : "R"
                },
                {
                    "main_4" : "D",
                    "main_5" : "E",
                    "main_10": "P"
                }
            ],
            "main_score": 0.1
        },
        {
           "main_id": "1334",
            "main_sub": [
                {
                    "main_info": {
                        "main_1" : "B",
                        "main_2" : "Q",
                        "main_3" : "C",
                        "main_11": "D"
                    },
                    "main_4" : "S",
                    "main_5" : "E",
                    "main_6" : "G",
                    "main_7" : "T"
                },
                {
                    "main_6" : "F",
                    "main_7" : "G",
                    "main_info": {
                        "main_1" : "A",
                        "main_2" : "I",
                        "main_3" : "J"
                    },
                    "main_10": "W",
                    "main_4" : "D",
                    "main_5" : "E",  
                    "main_act": [
                        {
                            "main_act_1": 112,
                            "main_act_1_1": "C",
                            "main_act_1_2": "T"
                        },
                        {
                            "main_act_1": 123,
                            "main_act_1_1": "D",
                            "main_act_1_2": "T"
                        }
                    ],
                    "main_8" : "R"
                },
                {
                    "main_4" : "D",
                    "main_5" : "E",
                    "main_10": "P"
                }
            ],
            "main_score": 0.1
        }
    ],
    "main_count": 2
}
```

I am not able to read a large part of this data due to the nesting even after I use $.each in jQuery.

Also is there a way by which I could read every single line of this json data and print it on screen without actually mentioning the field names like "main_1" in my jQuery code ?

**Output Expected :**

I would just want to print the field names as well as well as their values for each of the two instances of main .

Somewhat like :

```
main_id - 1234
main_sub -
  main_info - 
    main_1 - A
    main_2 - B
```

**and so on..................** (for both instances of main - thus the main_count = 2 at the end of the json data)

Comment: you dont need `$.each` to parse this json.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh alright so any other method by which i could read through the entire data?

Comment: it would be better if you could tell us what is the output you are expecting. Along with your attempt.

Comment: If you have a recursive data structure, you probably need a recursive algorithm, or at least a stack of contexts.

Comment: @JanDvorak : i am sorry but i don't get what a stack of contexts means ? Could you please state an example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure JS solution. This will list whole object in console.

```
var myVar = {..(your object data here)..};

function listing(obj, prefix){
    for(var key in obj){
        var el = obj[key];

        if(el instanceof Object){
            listing(el, prefix + ' | ' + key);
        }
        else{
            console.log(prefix + ' | ' + key + ': ' + el);
            //document.write(prefix + ' | ' + key + ': ' + el + '<br />'); //alternatively writing to document
        }
    }
}

listing(myVar, '');
```

Expected output:

```
 | main | 0 | main_id: 1234
 | main | 0 | main_sub | 0 | main_info | main_1: A
 | main | 0 | main_sub | 0 | main_info | main_2: B
 | main | 0 | main_sub | 0 | main_info | main_3: C
 | main | 0 | main_sub | 0 | main_4: D
 | main | 0 | main_sub | 0 | main_5: E
 | main | 0 | main_sub | 1 | main_6: F
 | main | 0 | main_sub | 1 | main_7: G
```

and so on..

Comment: I tried this  , but it doesn't seem to work , no data being displayed when i changed console.log to instead print it on screen in the body

Comment: If you want to write it to document use `document.write(prefix + ' | ' + key + ': ' + el + '<br />');`. Are you sure your data is parsed to object already? This could be string.

Answer (score 1):

this code is may be help full to you

```
       success: function(data)
           {
               if(data)
                   {

                        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                        $(json).each(function(i,val)
                        {
                            //your code  
                            $(val).each(function(index,val)
                             {
                                    //your code
                             });



                       });
                 }
          }
```

Comment: I am familiar with this structure for extracting json data from a file , but what I am facing a problem with is the code that would go into the $.each nested functions so that I could traverse through the entire data ?

Comment: you know recursive function.
try it.

Answer (score 0):

If this json is the result of a request, tel jQuery it should expect json, as an answer, and use the result as a plain javascript object :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'my/url',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) { // 'data' will be an object, not a string
        data.main[0].main_sub[1].main_6; //should be "F"
    }
});
```

If your json data is stored in a string, use `jQuery.parseJSON` to turn it into an object :

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonString);
data.main[0].main_sub[1].main_6; //should be "F"
```

Comment: but by this format , wouldn't I be required to hard code every line of data in order to print it on screen ?

Comment: data.main[0].main_sub[1].main_6;

this doesn't work , when i alert it , it says that it is undefined.